# How many 3-digit integers are divisible by the digit in their ones place?

Tags: combinatorics

How many 3-digit integers are divisible by the digit in their ones place?

I tried and got 90 for **1; 90 for **2; 3 for 1*3; 3 for 2*3; 4 for 3*3 so far, is this about listing out each unit digit and figure out the number of possible ways? quite tedious if so and wondering if there's any better way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the divisibility tests to help.  For $3$ you need the sum of the first two digits to be a multiple of $3$.  For $4$ you need the tens digit to be even.  For $5$ anything works.  For $6$ you again need the sum of the first two digits to be a multiple of $3$.  For $7$ you need the leading two digits to make a number divisible by $7$.  For $8$ you need tens digit to be even and the hundreds digit to be even iff the tens digit is a multiple of $4$.  For $9$ you need the sum of the first two digits to be a multiple of $9$.

Comment: `Length@Select[Range[1000],  Mod[#, 10] != 0 && Mod[#, Mod[#, 10]] == 0 &]` gives $470$. and for a million:  $467066$

Comment: For the case of $8$ we have $128/8 = 16$ and $228/8 = 28.5$ so is the "hundreds and tens digit being even" check perhaps incorrect?

Comment: @WaveX:  You are right.  Corrected.

Comment: Length@Select[Range[1000], Mod[#, 10] != 0 && Mod[#, Mod[#, 10]] == 0 &] gives 470. and for a million: 467066 --- what language is this, maybe Excel? the provided answer for under 1000 was 420 - what's the difference here

Comment: @user526427:  this is Mathematica code.  I believe the difference is this code goes from 1 to 999, while your problem goes from 100 to 999 because you demand three digit numbers.  I get $420$ for the range $100-999$ with Excel

Comment: @DavidG.Stork:  The range should be $100-999$ because the problem asked for three digit numbers.  I get $420$ over that range.

Comment: Yep:  $420$..........

Comment: @user526427:  the equivalent expression in Excel is =IF(MOD(Left,MOD(Left,10))=0,1,0) where Left has the number to test and it outputs $1$ if the number satisfies the requirement.  You can then add up the range of interest to find how many there are.  The inner MOD picks off the ones digit of the number and the outer one checks the divisibility of the whole number by that.

Comment: The Excel expression is quite cool, except it generates #DIV/0 for digit 0, otherwise it'll be perfect

Comment: @user526427:  yes, I had made the list of possible numbers avoiding multiples of $10$, so didn't have that problem.  You could wrap it in =IF(MOD(Left,10)=0,0,that) to avoid it.  That is the purpose of the first part of the Mathematica, to skip the multiples of 10.